# Firebug console and css errors

Tags: css, console, firebug

I am getting the following error in Firebug (console -> show css errors)

```
Expected ',' or '{' but found '0.2'.
```

This is on a page with jCarousel.

Is there a way to get more information about this error in Firebug, I can't find it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Found this:

```
ul, ol {
    margin-left 0;
}
```

on this example page:
http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html

i.e. `margin-left` is not followed by a colon.

Comment: I can't find that error? Which css file and which line did you see that?

Comment: If you open firebug, and select the dropdown in the 'Console' tab, and make sure 'Show CSS errors' is checked, then that error will appear when you load the link I provided. It also says `styles.css (line 46)`

Comment: +1 Learned something new, I didn't realize you can display css errors, thanks!